# SaveFileDialog exception in my WPF app

Tags: wpf, savefiledialog, special-folders, argumentexception

One of my customers is experiencing a crash in my WPF application when saving a file.

My save file code is:

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog {
  InitialDirectory = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"\MyApp"),
  FileName = "MyFile", 
  OverwritePrompt = true,
  AddExtension = true
};

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
  ...
}
```

And here is the exception they are getting:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.

A System.ArgumentException occurred
   at MS.Internal.Interop.HRESULT.ThrowIfFailed(String message)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ShellUtil.GetShellItemForPath(String path)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.PrepareVistaDialog(IFileDialog dialog)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunVistaDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
   at Microsoft.Win32.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
```

(Where the `ShowDialog` in the last line refers to the call I make in my code above.)

So my hunch is that in my customer's case, the call to Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) is returning something that the `SaveFileDialog` does not like as the `InitialDirectory`. I've found in web searches (and validated) that this error occurs when passing a relative path as the `InitialDirectory` of the SaveFileDialog. Is it possible that `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` could be returned as a relative path? If not, does anybody know another potentially invalid format? Could a certain SpecialFolder.MyDocuments network path be the cause? Any other ideas?

I don't have direct access to my customer's machine and they aren't particularly tech savvy so it's not possible to be 100% certain what is happening.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385619/issue-with-debugging-visual-studio-2010-solution-that-utilises-filedialog-from-t and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433373/wpf-vb-net-openfiledialog-showdialog-throws-an-exception?

Comment: Yep, both unrelated. First is to do with relative file paths (which I specifically ask about in my question with regard to SpecialFolder.MyDocuments). The second has an answer that I can't even see being related to the original question - regardless, it doesn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() throws an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433373/openfiledialog-showdialog-throws-an-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
InitialDirectory = string.Concat(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    @"\MyApp"
)
```

`Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` was being returned on my customer's machine with a trailing '\' character, and so the complete concatenated path had a double '\' in it.

`SaveFileDialog` crashes when you pass an `InitialDirectory` path containing a double '\' (which is a flaw in my opinion - it should more gracefully handle or coerce invalid inputs).

I use the `Path.Combine` static method instead now to handle both variants:

```
InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    "MyApp"
)
```

And it crashes no more.

Answer (score 8):

I found that using

```
fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relPath);
```

eliminated the problem for me.
Apparently, `FileDialog.ShowDialog` does not like relative `InitialDirectory` values.

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the same problem:

The exception also happens when `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` points to a network drive (domain environment) and it somehow is not reachable. Then `GetFullPath` or `Path.Combine` does not help.

I solved it catching the exception and calling ShowDialog a second time after setting InitialDirectory to the System Root, e.g. "C:\".